# OnItemSelectedListener does not reached when selecting item fron spinner and AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android, android-spinner, autocompletetextview

I'm trying to set OnItemSelectedListener to a Spinner and a AutoComplete textView and according to my logcat the whole OnItemSelectedListener is never reached

CODE:

```
public class ContactEditFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener,
    OnItemSelectedListener {
...
static Spinner reminderSelect;
private static AutoCompleteTextView contactWith;
...
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
        reminderSelect = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.reminder_selector);
    reminderSelect.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

 ...// Adapter and stuff
contactWith = (AutoCompleteTextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.contactWith);
    contactWith.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

The OnItemSelectedListener:

```
  @Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
        long id) {

    Log.wtf("fd", "GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG");


    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.reminder_selector:

                   Log.wtf("fd", "FFFFFFF"); // never reached

        choosenReminder = Integer.toString(pos);
        switch (pos) {
        case 5: //Custom reminder

            reminderSpinnerParent = parent;
            DialogFragment newFragmentTime = new TimePickerFragment();   
            Bundle argsTime = new Bundle();
            argsTime.putInt("customReminder", 2);
            newFragmentTime.setArguments(argsTime);      
            newFragmentTime.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
            setCustomReminderText(reminderSpinnerParent);
            choosenReminder = customReminderText;

            break;
        default:
            break;
            }


    case R.id.contactWith:
        isAutoCompleted = true;
        break;


    }
}
```

the Line

```
Log.wtf("fd", "GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG");
```

appears in the LogCat only when the whole fragment is being inflated, the line

```
Log.wtf("fd", "FFFFFFF");
```

is never being posted to the logcat
why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I got it right, The problem was that I was missing some break;(s) there